# Parsing a string in D

Tags: string, parsing, d

I'm trying to learn D but am struggling with lack of documentation (or my understanding of it), so I came here. I already asked a different but unrelated question earlier today.

Anyway, here goes:

I would like to parse a string for different things.

String format is something like:

```
[<label>] <mnemonic> [parameters]
```

If there is no label, there is mandatory whitespace. Parameters can be comma-delimited. Parameter types are dependent on the mnemonic.

I would like to use `std.conv: parse` from the Phobos library to aid me, but I fail to understand the documentation on how to parse a "word", as in, some characters seperated by whitespace on either end. It works fine for integers and the like as `int i = parse!int(line)`. But if I were to do `string s = parse!string(line)` it would grab the entire line.

I cold parse this by hand, using `char**` (or, `ref string`) as a datatype, just like I did when I wrote this in C. But I'm learning D to not have to.

I tried something like this to do it manually:

```
string get_word(ref string s)
{
        int i = 0;
        while (i < s.length && isAlphaNum(s[i]))
                i++;

        string word = s[0 .. i];
        s = s[i+1 .. $];
        return word;
}
```

Is this a good way to do it? Is there a cleaner way? A faster way? A safer way, perhaps? I'm not sure the `i+1` index always exists.

Thanks for the help!

My faith in D is slightly dwindling already, as I've run into all sorts of problems. But the path is surely going to be worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code is wrote on the fly

```
import std.string;
import std.stdio;
import std.algorithm;
import std.math;

enum string[] separators = [ " ", "\t", ",", ";", "\n", "\r\n" ];

string get_word( ref string s ){
    string token;
    sizediff_t storePositions[separators.length + 1]; // set size array to the number of separator in array "separators" and latest field for current string lenght 
    foreach( i, separator; separators ){             // compute position for each separator
        sizediff_t position = countUntil( s, separator );
        if( position == -1 ) position = sizediff_t.max;
        storePositions[i] = position;
    }
    storePositions[ $ -1 ] = s.length;
    sizediff_t end    = reduce!min( storePositions );
    token             = s[0 .. end].idup;
    writefln( "%s | %d", s, end );
    return token;
}

void main( string[] args ){
    string s        = "a long;string\tyeah\n strange; ok";
    bool   isRunning= true;
    size_t start    = 0;
    writefln( "parse: %s", s ); 
    while( isRunning ){
        string result = get_word( s[ start .. $] );
        if( result == "" )
            isRunning = false;
        else{
            start  += result.length + 1;
            result = get_word( s[ start .. $] );
        }
        writefln( "token: %s, position: %d", result, start );
        writeln( "----" );
    } 
}
```

output:

```
parse: a long;string yeah
 strange; ok
a long;string yeah
 strange; ok | 1
long;string yeah
 strange; ok | 4
token: long, position: 2
----
long;string yeah
 strange; ok | 4
string yeah
 strange; ok | 6
token: string, position: 7
----
string yeah
 strange; ok | 6
yeah
 strange; ok | 4
token: yeah, position: 14
----
yeah
 strange; ok | 4
 strange; ok | 0
token: , position: 19
----
 strange; ok | 0
token: , position: 19
```

---

Comment: Does this advance the string? Also, what happens if it hits newline? Also, doesn't it go through the string twice?

Oh and, it seems to work with and without `.idup`, could you explain why?

Comment: this little function just store the position of first whitespace and do same thing for ";". The little position show the end you need use for slice.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. But how would I use the "isWhite" function with countUntil? I can't seem to make it work. I want the negation of "isWhite", though.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing: `countUntil!((auto c) {return !isWhite(c); })(s)` to get the index, then returned `s[i..$]` and modified `s` to `s[i+1..$]`.

I'll accept your answer, but I'd still like to know how to use the `std.conv: parse` library. :)

Comment: On another note!

The function `std.string: munch` does exactly what I need!

Comment: you can use instead munch this too: find!"a != ';'"(";;;;;blah");

Answer (score 2):

First of all, std.conv.parse is for converting things to strings, not parsing in the sense of separating and understanding a string. How complex of a solution you need will depend on the complexity of the grammar of your format string.
Look at std.string.split which, by default, will split your input on whitespace and return an array of the words.
If the format is too complex, you can:

1. use regex with captures: http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_regex.html#RegexMatch
2. write your own parser which advances character by character and extracts the info you need.

Comment: I've seen those too, but regex seemed a bit overkill. Split seems to do what I want, but is it efficient? It seems like I'd be going through the data twice.

Also, could you tell me how to get a hexadecimal number from a string in D? I found something like this in the Tango library, but I am using Phobos and D2.

Comment: If split does the job, but you're concerned about covering the data twice (I wouldn't unless you're doing very large, real-time jobs), consider std.string.munch.

Comment: Well, I'll rewrite the stuff when I have time into one of these options. The countUntil one is pretty ugly, albeit flexible. Thanks.